# Importing Data Using Unix to Oracle DB

Tags: database, bash, oracle, unix

I want to import data on a weekly basis to an Oracle DB.
I'm receiving this data on specific location in a server in EDR format. For now I'm uploading them manually using Toad for Oracle uploader wizard. Is there any way to upload them automatically using Unix or any kind of scripting?

Comment: Can you provide reference for EDR format?

Comment: here is a sample, note that each field is delimited with pipes

bash|112322|ahmed|0|20400101000000||2014|21001111090211|||ahmed|4525435333|jack|0|20400101000000||20191111090211|20111111090211|||

Comment: Check the answer below and read how to use `sqlldr`

Comment: Can you place the sample and the tabel in the question, not comment. You might select a 4 table with 4 columns, easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to try out SQL loader through a shell script.

**Code:**

```
sqlldr username@server/password control=loader.ctl
```

two important files:

a. your data file to be uploaded.

b. Control file which states the table to be inserted and the delimiter character and the column fields, etc. basically describe how to load the data.

[Oracle Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm)